# Error: Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of OpportunityLineItem

Tags: apex, class, opportunity-lineitem

i am getting this error in lin 12, how to pass multiple product code using list, can anyone please help me out.

> Error--Error: Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of OpportunityLineItem for column of type String at line 12 column 92

```
public class Procuct_Adding_To_Order{

public static void productOrder(List<OpportunityLineItem> oli){ 

   set<Id> setOppId = new set<Id>(); 

   for(OpportunityLineItem obj: oli){ 
        setOppId.add(obj.OpportunityId); 
   } 

   List<OpportunityLineItem> ProdCode = [Select ProductCode from OpportunityLineItem where id IN: oli];
   List<Product2> Prod_Nam = [Select id,Product_Abb__c from Product2 where ProductCode IN: ProdCode];
   List<opportunity> needed = [Select Master_Opportunity__c from opportunity Where Opportunity.id =: setOppId];
   List<OrderItem> orderIt = new List<OrderItem>();

    for(Order ord: [Select id from Order where opportunityId =: needed[0].Master_Opportunity__c])
      {
       for(OpportunityLineItem o : oli)
       {  
        for(Product2 pr : Prod_Nam)
        {
        OrderItem op = new OrderItem(); 
        op.Opportunity_del__c = needed[0].Master_Opportunity__c; 
        op.orderId = ord.id;
        op.Order_Name__c = Pr.Product_Abb__c;
        op.PriceBookEntryId = o.PriceBookEntryId;
        op.Quantity = o.Quantity;
        op.UnitPrice = 100;
        orderIt.add(op);
         }
          } 
        }
    upsert orderIt; 
}
}
```

Comment: you are creating self-inflicted wounds by your variable names. `prodCode` is really `oliList`; `prod_nam` is really `prodList`; `needed` is something like `oliOppoList`; that said the first three soqls could be combined as you can fetch Product2 parent fields from the OLI and OLI can be queried for `opportunityId`. Using maps instead of lists is so much more useful and can avoid the loops within loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first SOQL, thou you are only querying for product codes, you will get back opportunity line item in the list.

```
List<OpportunityLineItem> ProdCode = [Select ProductCode from OpportunityLineItem where id IN: oli];
```

So, in your second SOQL you are passing OpportunityLineItem list instead of product codes.

```
List<Product2> Prod_Nam = [Select id,Product_Abb__c from Product2 where ProductCode IN: ProdCode];
```

to fix this, after your first query, iterate and store the product codes into a separate collection / array and use it in your second SOQL.

something like

```
List<String> ProdCodes = new List<String>();
List<OpportunityLineItem> olList = [Select ProductCode from OpportunityLineItem where id IN: oli];
for(OpportunityLineItem ol : olList){
    ProdCodes.add(ol.ProductCode);
}
List<Product2> Prod_Nam = [Select id,Product_Abb__c from Product2 where ProductCode IN: ProdCodes];
```

Comment: actually i don't want to pass product id , i just want to pass product code @Vamsi